# Disableing Nvidia GPUs on Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I am trying to move a mining farm on to Ubuntu... because Windows... On windows, I can disable GPUs to help with troubleshooting and checking for stability. I looked through the Ubuntu forums, and I wasn't able to find anything way of disabling them without tweaking the BIOs. If it's not possible to disable the GPUs with a command like "Nvidia-setting GPU[2]=off" then mabey a way for the GPU to be ignored by the mining software? [Windows device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWYbE.png) Running 8 Nvidia GPUs per Rig all Nvidia and I am currently using Claymore miner.

Comment: Also Perhaps if its possible to disable them using Cuda ? or just pointing me in the right direction. Anything Helps  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newer Linux versions there is an Nvidia driver built into the kernel, it’s called Nouveau. So maybe you can try to remove that driver. There is also a proprietary one by NVIDIA but I understand you don’t want that either.

My first thought was you’d have to recompile a kernel yourself, but there might be other options, e.g. see here:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found a workaround to my solution, Most mining software will let you chose which GPUs to mine on.